# dataTable how to take element from not current pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a Data table where first column contain a checkbox to check the id of element.

```html
<tbody>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">
      <input type="checkbox" value="2025" 
                class="checkElement n30" id="n30">
      <label for="n30">2025</label>
    </td>

  ...
```

The data table is made by 33 elements in 4 pages (10 per page)

I would like to filter the id of all checked elements that are in data-table, which include also the elements that are in pages different from the current one. 
Unfortunately when I use jquery to take element property I can take only the elements on the current page, and if I use the property checked from document element it returns always false as showed in the following code:

```js
        dt = $('#Table').DataTable();

        info = dt.page.info();
        for(i=0;i<info.pages;i++)
          {
            console.log("pagina ("+(i+1)+"): ");
            pdt = dt.page(i).rows().data();
            pdt.rows().data().each(function(row, index){
               console.log("riga ("+(index+1)+"): ");
               $(row[0]).each(function(pos, elem) {
                  var isSelected = $("#"+elem.id).prop('checked');
                  if(pos == 0)                                                
                    console.log(">> "+elem+": "+elem.checked+" / "+isSelected);
               });
            });
         } // end for
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I try to select only the first two elements of each page but in console the result is:

```
 pagina (1): 
   riga (1): 
          >> checkbox: false / true
   riga (2): 
          >> checkbox: false / true
 ...
   riga (9): 
          >> checkbox: false / false
   riga (10): 
          >> checkbox: false / false
   riga (11): 
          >> checkbox: false / undefined
   riga (12): 
          >> checkbox: false / undefined
   riga (13): 
          >> checkbox: false / undefined
 ...
   riga (28): 
          >> checkbox: false / undefined
   riga (29): 
          >> checkbox: false / undefined
   riga (30): 
          >> checkbox: false / undefined
   riga (31): 
          >> checkbox: false / undefined
   riga (32): 
          >> checkbox: false / undefined
   riga (33): 
          >> checkbox: false / undefined
```

In pages 2, 3, 4 there is the same log;
How can I have only and all the checked elements in whole pages?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are using server side method, is not possible to filter because just page 1 is processed and the other data on page 2-3-4 doesn't exist because they are not yet retrieved from db. You can increment the result nr per page to show for example 50 rows and have the desired result or if your table data is not supposed to be very big you can use the client side model of DT so all the data are processed and retrieved from db and just divided with pagination for better organisation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using client-side processing mode, you can access elements on other pages by using [`$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) API method.

For example:

```
var dt = $('#Table').DataTable();
console.log(dt.$('#checkbox-id').prop('checked'));
```

If you're using server-side processing mode, as [Sigma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52721916/datatable-how-to-take-element-from-not-current-pages#comment92386196_52721916) commented, it's not easy because data from other pages do not exist in DOM.

[jQuery DataTables Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) supports [server-side processing mode](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/data-sources/server-side/), see if you want to use it in your project.